# How to Read/write zOS(Mainframe) flat file using spring batch

Tags: java, spring-boot, io, spring-batch, zos

I am developing spring batch application that should be executed/triggered on zOS (Mainframe). I have to read/write the flat file in zos as a input file in spring batch and do some processing. do we have some working examples ? does spring batch has the capability of reading direct Mainframe flat files ? If so can you give me some working example. Thanks in advance

Comment: "Mainframe flat files" is a bit of a loaded statement.  I do have some code that demonstrates reading files defined via COBOL copybooks.  You can find that here: https://github.com/mminella/COBOL-SpringXD-Source.  But if you can provide more insights into what, specifically, you are looking to read, I can provide more clear guidance.

Comment: Hi Michael, I want to read a simple coma separated values file. but I have to use spring batch as it has something called ItemReader interface. which has multiple implementations like FlatFileReader etc. I want to know if I can read Mainframe file by using this reader supplied by spring batch. if yes some reference/sample code.

Comment: If it's an ASCII file, you should be able to read it with existing tools.  If it's EBCDIC, you'll need to use your own `ItemReader` implementation.

Comment: Yes, it is ASCII file. I saw your demo on github. if I am using the predefined FlatFileItemReader and assume my flat file is SB950.BLPRIC.BL376T2.D1511700 (same as yours) . will the below code works ? 
FlatFileItemReader reader = new FlatFileItemReader();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("SB950.BLPRIC.BL376T2.D1511700"));
what is the significance of "/data" from your example ?

Comment: @Swaroop do you have a Cobol Copybook   ???, Since it is an ascii file, you should be able to handle it as a standard fixed width file.

Comment: If you have a `Cobol` copybook, I have been playing around with Java Code generation (as a standalone application in JRecord + via RecordEditor http://record-editor.sourceforge.net//RecordEditorGenerate.htm). It `may` possible to generate something. I do not know anything about spring batch though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [ZFile](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.zsecurity.api.70.doc/com.ibm.jzos/com/ibm/jzos/ZFile.html) class in the z/OS SDK to read flat files (data sets). There's some useful samples to get your started https://github.com/zsystems/java-samples. It's basically a JNI wrapper over the C/C++ stdio fopen() and friends runtime library functions.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, able to solve the problem with this info.
https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-497
As David said we have to ZFile and other classes from jzos provided by IBM. I am able to read the flat file from zos using spring batch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use charset cp1047 when reading inputstream.